# ImageMagick on PHP 5.3

Tags: php, iis, imagemagick

I'm trying to install ImageMagick on this environment:

IIS 7.5
Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1) i586  x86 
MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
PHP 5.3.13

I'm following this steps:

http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/

I always get this error: * PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
*

Which image_magick.dll and imageMagick installer should I use in my case?

Thanks in advance
Javier

Comment: Which installer did you use?

Comment: Hi Kev! I tried with this installers:                       ImageMagick-6.8.9-5-Q16-x86-dll.exe  
ImageMagick-6.8.9-5-Q16-x86-static.exe